# How to put the default calculator into radian mode?

Tags: 18.04, calculator, gnome-calculator

I am trying to do calculus. Is there a way to put the default calculator into radian mode? I can't find anything about it.

[image]

Comment: gnome-calculator has a default plus 4 other modes. To specifically start in a mode use `--mode=mode`. It always opens in last closed mode. If you want a mode not included in those 5 provided then find a different calculator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by editing the settings in the `dconf` database - either with the `dconf-editor` or using `gsettings`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.calculator angle-units 'radians'
```

You will probably want to reverse the default angle conversion as well

```
gsettings set org.gnome.calculator source-units 'radian'
gsettings set org.gnome.calculator target-units 'degree'
```

Viz.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using version 42.2, and you can do that directly from the application's preferences